# Плавная смена текстуры

Tags: spritekit, xcode, objective-c, ios7

```
Rad = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Rad.png"];
SKAction *act = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Rad2.png"]];
act.duration = 10;
[Rad runAction:act];
```

Текстура меняется, но не плавно, почему?

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но почитайте [документацию][1] или хотя бы посмотрите курс Simon Allardice по SpriteKit. Все Ваши вопросы по нему от того что Вы не прикладываете усилий чтобы понять как он работает.

[1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH1-SW1

Comment: В общем я воспользовался Atlas'ом.